# Check if a view was created with the FORCE option

Tags: oracle, view

How can I check in Oracle if a view was created with the FORCE option?

In the view `sys.all_views` there is no column for this option and the query text itself doesn't contain the CREATE part.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912601/oracle-force-view-option-isnt-shown-on-view-after-executed

Comment: That means the FORCE option vanishes after the view is compiled? And how does Toad know that the view was created with the FORCE option?

Comment: This is why I didn't mark question as duplicate

Comment: Why would Toad need to know this ? And why do you need this information ?

Comment: I assume TOAD doesn't "know" it, it simply adds the FORCE option to every CREATE VIEW statement it generates - just to be sure. As far as I can tell, `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` (which might be used by TOAD) also adds that option unconditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm what @a_horse_with_no_name suggested: `FORCE` isn't stored in the data dictionary, and `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` makes it up, as probably TOAD does, too:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i NUMBER);
CREATE FORCE   VIEW f AS SELECT * FROM t;
CREATE NOFORCE VIEW n AS SELECT * FROM t;
```

`USER_VIEWS`, `USER_OBJECTS`, `SYS.VIEW$` and `SYS.OBJ$` are identical for the two views. And `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` adds `FORCE` in any case:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', view_name) FROM user_views;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "SO"."F" ("I") AS 
SELECT "I" FROM t"

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "SO"."N" ("I") AS 
SELECT "I" FROM t"
```